# gcc installed via homebrew doesn't have manpages

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I installed `gcc` 4.9 via Homebrew but I don't have any manpages for `gcc` or `g++`. (That is, `man gcc` and `man g++` show `No manual entry for gcc`/`No manual entry for g++`). How can I get manpages for `gcc` and `g++`?

Comment: Just a note... I've heard that Linux Torvalds recommends avoiding GCC 4.9; he says that it generates incorrect code. So personally I stick with GCC 4.8.3 on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't like using the names `gcc` and `g++`, since they're already in use by the operating system, and will refuse to link to `gcc` and `g++`. Instead it links `gcc-4.9` and `g++-4.9`.

In the same way, you can access the manpages with `man gcc-4.9` rather than `man gcc` and `man g++-4.9` rather than `man g++`.